# How can I download a .webarchive with ASIHTTPRequest?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, asihttprequest

I was just wondering how I can download a .webarchive from my UIWebView using ASIHTTPRequest. I've looked at their documentation but unfortunately, it doesn't mention anything about saving web archives.

I noticed that [this app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/download-manager-pro/id334640492?mt=8) saves .webarchives to the iOS device and loads them.

Comment: Does ASIWebPageRequest http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest not do what you want?

Comment: well I think it does (based on other SO questions) but I just don't know how to use it to save .webarchive files. If I could have a pointer in the right direction, that would be great :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive :

> "The webarchive format is a concatenation of source files with
>   filenames saved in the binary plist format using NSKeyedEncoder"

As jbat100 mentions, the [ASIWebPageRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ASIWebPageRequest) code is likely to be a useful starting point - you'll need to write code to do the saving of the files into the binary plist format yourself.

Comment: Thanks! What kind of code would I need to write to do the saving of the files? Could you give me a short example for one .webarchive please?

Comment: There's Mac OS code to create one here: https://github.com/newzealandpaul/webarchiver - that should give you a good start...